# Removing trailing newlines with regex in Ruby's 'String#scan'

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string, which contains a bunch of HTML documents, tagged with `@name`:

```
string = "@one\n\n<html>\n</html>\n\n@two\n<html>\n</html>\n\n\n"
```

I want to get an array of two-element arrays, each of which with a tag as the first element and the HTML document as the second:

```
[ ["@one", "<html>\n</html>"], ["@two", "<html>\n</html>"] ]
```

In order to solve the problem, I crafted the following regular expression:

```
regex = /(@.+)\n+([^@]+)\n+/
```

and applied it in `string.scan regex`.

However, instead of the desired output, I get the following:

```
[ ["@one", "<html>\n</html>\n"], ["@two", "<html>\n</html>\n\n"] ]
```

There are trailing newline characters at the end of each document. It appears that only one newline character was removed from the documents, but others stayed at the place.

How can the aforementioned regular expression be changed in order to remove all the trailing characters from the resulting documents?

Comment: try /(@.+)\n+([^@]+)(?:\n+)/

Answer (score 0):

The reason only the last `\n` was thrown away is because the two relevant capturing parts in your regex: `.+` and `[^@]+` capture everything up to the last `\n` (in order to make matching possible at all). It does not matter that they are followed by `\n+`. Remember that regex works from the left to the right. If some substring (sequences of `\n` in this case) can fit in either the preceding part of the following part of a regex, it actually fits in the preceding part.

With generality, I would suggest doing this:

```
string.split(/\s+(?=@)/).map{|s| s.strip.split(/\s+/, 2)}
# => [["@one", "<html>\n</html>"], ["@two", "<html>\n</html>"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplicated newlines first:

```
string.gsub(/\n+/, "\n").scan(regex)

=> [["@one", "<html>\n</html>"], ["@two", "<html>\n</html>"]]
```